# select query on dataset in winforms program throw me an error

Tags: c#, winforms

i have `dataset` in my C# program and i try to run query

```
DataRow[] drTitles = dsConf.Tables[1].Select("Distinct SNum");
```

but i got error

```
Syntax error: Missing operand after 'SNum' operator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select is for filtering
use to table in data view to get distinct row
Use this syntax

```
System.Data.DataView dv = new System.Data.DataView(dsConf.Tables[1]);
System.Data.DataTable dt = dv.ToTable(true,"SNum");
```

Answer (score 1):

This Select is not equivalent to the select clause used in SQL. Here, the role of the `Select` method is to filter, so you need to specify a filter parameter, like `"Name = 'Cindy'"`. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx).